# javafx in java swing crashes when closed

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, stack-trace

I have embedded javafx 2.2 application in swing using **JFXPanel**, but sometimes it crashes when I close the application.

**Stack Trace**:

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PaintRenderJob@11cf9944 rejected from
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer@5457487e[Terminated, pool
>   size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 25]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2013)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:816)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1337)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.submitRenderJob(QuantumRenderer.java:206)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.addRenderJob(QuantumToolkit.java:408)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene.repaint(EmbeddedScene.java:106)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PaintCollector.renderAll(PaintCollector.java:410)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:461)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:329)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Edit:
As it is in swing application it has

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: similar bug was fixed in early 2.2 https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22658 -- what version of FX and platform do you use?

Comment: am using java fx 2.2 jdk 1.7.0_10 in eclipse 3.6.1

Comment: then you may want to try to update to latest jdk/fx (which is 1.7.0_25 ATM)

Comment: in my version javafx version is 2.2.25-b15 (and I guess they have fixed in b17 am using jdk1.7.0.25) so what should I do.
I just want to close application gracefully (is there any way to catch this exception.)